# Parallax scrolling sprite in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, scroll, sprite

I have attempted to recreate the effect from [this smashing tutorial](http://richardshepherd.com/smashing/parallax/), (see the scrolling sprite) but I have gotten completely stumped. I've been at this for days.

In the smashing version, the hovering sprite scrolls at a different speed than its parent background, creating a layered/3D effect. In my version, the sprite scrolls along with its parent background at the same speed.

Their version looks like this in Chrome inspector:
[image]

And their HTML:
[image]

My version:
[image]

And my HTML:
[image]

Notice how the smashing version has that inline style/percentage, but not on mine? I cannot for the life of me figure it out. I'm not getting any errors, I've toyed with the jQuery version, I've confirmed that all of the scripts they used are also loading on my page.

[My version is here.](http://aardvark.milespfefferle.com/)

Any ideas of what I may have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 25 of script.js it's looking for the section tag with a data-type="background"

```
$('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
```

You are using article tags instead of section tags so it's not going to work. You can structure your html more like the tutorial or change up the script a little like the following.

```
$('article[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
```

or like this to get any tag with data-type="background"

```
$('[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
```

If you do change up the script instead of structuring it more like the tutorial you may encounter other problems that may have to be worked around.